# Rails sqlserver: RuntimeError: Unknown bind columns. We can account for this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've updated my sqlserver database to SQL 2008 R2.

Now I've faced with strange problem - when I try to make a query like

`Prefix::Model.first`

I get a result (seems empty)

`=> #<Prefix::Model >`

when I try

`Prefix::Model.first.ID`

I get an id of object

Also not working queries like

`Prefix::Model.find_by_field('value')` =>

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_field' for Prefix::Model():Class
```

When I try `Prefix::Model.find(1)` I get

`RuntimeError: Unknown bind columns. We can account for this.`

my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.17'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'tiny_tds'
```

example model:

```
class Prefix::Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name =   "tbl_ModelTable"
  self.primary_key =  "ID"
end
```

Comment: show the model `Prefix::Model` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution: the cause of problem was the database user was not a member of the `db_owner` group and hadn't some permissions.